How to get the status of ipv6 off/on using networksetup?
Based on previous research, I created the following two Bash aliases to turn ipv6 off and on:
alias ipv6off="networksetup -setv6off 'USB 10/100/1000 LAN'"
alias ipv6on="networksetup -setv6automatic 'USB 10/100/1000 LAN'"

The question now is how to get the current state of my IPv6, whether it's on or off.
The manual of networksetup doesn't mention such an option that I found.
Is there a trick to get this information from the command line?
The context of this is that the VPN provider I use doesn't support IPv6 so I need to turn it off when I use it.

This command will tell you what you want to know:
networksetup -getinfo 'USB 10/100/1000 LAN'


Thanks! That worked.

Actually, I don't see a difference in the output before or after I execute the off/on aliases above.
